# How to push new data when I use useInfiniteQuery?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm building chat app in React using react-query. I implemented infinite scrolling using `useInfiniteQuery` hook, so when I scroll up, new messages are fetched. Now, when I post new message using `useMutation` hook, I want to append that new message to message array. I don't want to invalidate query because in that situation all pages that I previously fetched are fetched again. I also tried to set new data with `setQueryData(key)`, but UI is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
    const { mutate: mutateSendMessage } = useMutation({
     mutationFn: postMessage,
     onSuccess: (newMessage) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(['messages', chatId], (existingMessages) => {
       
        if (!existingMessages) return existingMessages;

        // this is not updating UI
        const newData = { ...existingMessages };
 
        newData.pages[0].results.unshift(newMessage);

        newData.pages[0].count += 1;

        return newData;
        
        // I don't want this
        // queryClient.invalidateQueries(['messages', chatId]);

      });
 
    }
  });
```

```
const {
    data,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    isPending,
    isFetching,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['messages', chatId],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam = 1 }) => getChatMessages(chatId, pageParam),
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      if (lastPage.prevPage * LIMIT >= lastPage.count) {
        return null;
      }

      return lastPage.prevPage + 1;
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with how you update the cache.
you would try

```
const [firstPage, ...restOfThePages] = existingMessages;
const newFirstPage = {...firstPage, results: [newMessage, ...firstPage.results], count: firstPage.count++ };

const newPages = [newFirstPage, ...restOfThePages];

return {
   ...existingMessages,
   pages: newPages

}
```